# Retornar dados do relacionamento e gerar PDF no Laravel/DomPdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Olá, estou com um problema e encontrei uma parte da solução aqui, eu estou tratando disso de uma maneira diferente em outra pergunta, porém resolvi testar uma forma que vi aqui do usuário Vigilio sobre DomPDF
O meu caso é o seguinte, eu tenho curso e alunos, eu preciso retornar todos os alunos cadastrados em um curso em PDF, eu consigo retornar normalmente, porém quando tento retornar em pdf ele diz que falta um argumento, segue os códigos

PdfviewController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Curso;
use App\Aluno;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

class PdfviewController extends Controller
{

    private $model;
    public function __construct(Curso $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function index($id)
    {       
            $data['model'] = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
            $alunos = $curso->alunos;
        return PDF::loadView('viewpdf.index', $data, $alunos)->stream();
    }
}
```

Rota

```
Route::get('/viewpdf', 'PdfviewController@index');
```

index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Curso</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($alunos as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->nome}}</td>

            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu estou com dúvidas se devo passar o ID pela rota nesse caso, mas toda vez que tento o resultado é o mesmo

(1/1) ErrorException
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PdfviewController::index()

Answer (score 1):

A rota deve ser

```
Route::get('/{id}/viewpdf', 'PdfviewController@index');
```

Caso o parâmetro fosse opcional ainda sim você teria que usar

```
Route::get('/{id?}/viewpdf', 'PdfviewController@index');
```

Comment: Vou já testar isso, mas no controller, segue do mesmo jeito?

Comment: Sim, o controller fica igual, normalmente eu n uso findOrFail uso só o find, mas serve tbm

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte maneira, creio que resolva seu problema:

```
return PDF::loadView('viewpdf.index', compact('data', 'alunos'))->stream();
```